# Move Picture in div and cut positions and upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

i tried a lot of examples but nothing works as i want it to be.
It's for touch screen only devices (app) and i use jquery 1.8.3.

What i do is i upload a photo and it fetches the photo from the server and put it in a div.
In that div, i need to be able to move the photo around to whatever i want it to be.
When i click next it will cut the part out of the photo that i selected (the server can do this).

I tried canvas, but it doesn't work on touchscreen devices.

What i try to ask is:

Is there a way to move the background in a div, and what i see in the div (user point of view) is what the picture is going to be, get the cordinates and submit them to the server.
The server will cut a square out that picture (with that cordinates) and maybe even a rotate and saves it.

The server part is not an issue, it's the moving in div en getting cordinates.

Or does anyone have a better idea  (i want the instagram like how to select a square out of a picture)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the element in the background [draggable.](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) Once it's draggable, then the user can drag it around any certain way.

Finally, when the submit button is clicked, you can check to see what part of the picture is inside the box.

Comment: Thanks, i tried it and it did work for a few seconds. I wonder if i can put a div in a div, so one div that contains the background and the div that i can drag (this is what the example shows) this (see code) i don't see the dragable part: <div id="canvasphoto" style="width: 720px; height: 500px; max-width: 100%; max-height: 500px; float: left;" align="center">

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>

</div>